# Why does Firefox execute Javascript in the referring window's/tab's context when target="_blank" is used with a data:uri?

Tags: javascript, firefox, xss

I set a link's target to _blank. With the href attribute set to a data-uri with a script tag, and the previous window's context executes the javascript. Does this happen with using window.open()? This would allow an attacker with XSS to steal localStorage data, and there is apparently no way for a developer to isolate a window's execution context. My question is, why does a data:uri execute script in the previous window's (i.e the window with the target="_blank" attribute set) context even though it opens in a new tab? And, how is a developer supposed to isolate a window's Javascript context, since _blank doesn't do it?  I thought _blank meant new window, new execution context, but I think _new acts the same way.

Comment: i would assume that since the dataURL document came from your site, you can trust it.

Comment: What about Roundcube or online instant messengers?  The content could come from someone else?  Should the site blindly filter all dataUris?  What is the purpose of _blank then?  This question is more about the responsibility of Firefox to reduce attack surface, so I am looking for more of the purpose of this functionality.  Not assuming that the site that provides the link is secure, because we know that isn't always true.